# No Suitable MessageConverter

Tags: json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a spring boot application and am testing integration test. My REST service produces JSON and I can confirm it when testing it in postman.

But when I make a getForObject call by restTemplate:

```
 @Test
    public void testGetObject() {
        Pet pet = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9000/pets/10000", User.class, Collections.emptyMap());
        assertThat(pet.getName(), is("Bobby"));
    }
```

It fails with following error:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class petstore.entity.User] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
```

I read lots of posts in stackoverflow, and having that restTempalte itself has ***MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter*** as one of default converters which has ***JSON as default media type*** then I should not get this error.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message is pretty indicative - you're getting `text/html` as a response type, make your endpoint return `application/json`. If you're using Spring MVC then you can do it by adding the produces parameter to the annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pets/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

Or, if you're using Jersey, add this annotation to your method:

```
@Produces("application/json")
```